# Updating upload_max_filesize in joomla

Tags: joomla, php

I am using frame work Joomla1.5. I am not able to submit form with multiple uploaded files having each file size more than 3mb. i tried to set `post_max_size`, `upload_max_size` parameters in layout `default.php(views/tmpl/default.php)` as

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '5M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '15M');
```

but that parameters still showing default sizes only. 
can you please tell me where/how to set value in joomla

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can set the maximum upload size in joomla from admin panel. You have to go site -> Global configuration -> System->Maximum Size (in bytes).

Answer (score 0):

Find the php.ini file that your server uses and change the 'upload_max_filesize' value to a higher number and restart the server.