# Why administrator in joomla can't value from php.ini?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I using host Cpanel, in php.ini i edit value upload_max _file_size from 2M (default) to 15M

Struct my host:

```
/www/administrator/
/www/components/    
    ... 
/www/php.ini
/www/test.php
```

In test.php i `echo phpinfo()` is result is
[image: php.ini]

But in joomla is i check sysinfo is result is
[image: php.ini]

How to fix upload_max_filesize in joomla,  i had restart this host apache

Comment: there may be more than one php.ini file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622652/updating-upload-max-filesize-in-joomla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create `php.ini` in `/www/administrator/php.ini`

add this code:

```
upload_max_filesize = 15M
post_max_size = 15M
```

Answer (score 1):

yup its true upload_max_filesize in php.info, but still 2M in joomla 2.5 system information  [jasa pembuatan website](http://www.joglomedia.net/)

Answer (score 0):

PHP.ini Configuration

```
upload_max_filesize: 15M
post_max_size: 90M
max_execution_time: 10000
memory_limit: 128M
```

Comment: you don't answer the question, the OP said that his php.ini is configured correctly.